# C++ chain inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, function-pointers, virtual-functions

Im trying to create a percent savings program for a supermarket with 3 inherited classes (**PersonData** -> **CustomerData** -> **PreferredCustomer**). The entire program has to follow this UML diagram:

[image: UML diagram]

I am having problems with the third class; specifically initializing values in the first constructor of the class. Im getting an error message in visual studio: "redefinition of formal parameter Pa" and "redefinition of formal parameter "dl".

This is the constructor with the errors:

```
PreferredCustomer(string aLname, string aFname, string aAddress, 
        string aCity, string aState, int aZip, string aPhone, int cn, 
        bool ml, double Pa, double dl)   // constructor 1
{
    double Pa;
    double dl;
}
```

The parameters in this third child constructor have been overloaded from the parent constructor. Arguments cn, ml, Pa, dl have all been added into this parameter.

I'm not sure why i am getting these errors? Also, should i be creating a virtual function or using pointers? Thank you for any help.

My program source code (for reference):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class PersonData // PersonData parent class defined
{
private:
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
    string address;
    string city;
    string state;
    string phone;
    int zip;

public:
    PersonData() // Default Constructor initialization
    {
        lastName = " ";
        firstName = " ";
        address = " ";
        city = " ";
        state = " ";
        zip = 0;
        phone = " ";
    }

    PersonData(string aLname, string aFname, string aAddress, string aCity, string aState, int aZip, string aPhone) // Constructor 1
    {
        lastName = aLname;
        firstName = aFname;
        address = aAddress;
        city = aCity;
        state = aState;
        zip = aZip;
        phone = aPhone;
    }

    // Accesor Functions
    string getLastName() const
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    string getFirstName() const
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    string getAddress() const
    {
        return address;
    }

    string getCity() const
    {
        return city;
    }

    string getState() const
    {
        return state;
    }

    int getZip() const
    {
        return zip;
    }

    string getPhone() const
    {
        return phone;
    }

    // Mutator Functions
    void setLastName(string aLname)
    {
        lastName = aLname;
    }

    void setFirstName(string aFname)
    {
        firstName = aFname;
    }

    void setAddress(string aAddress)
    {
        address = aAddress;
    }

    void setCity(string aCity)
    {
        city = aCity;
    }

    void setState(string aState)
    {
        state = aState;
    }

    void setZip(int aZip)
    {
        zip = aZip;
    }

    void setPhone(string aPhone)
    {
        phone = aPhone;
    }
};

class CustomerData :public PersonData // CustomerData child class of PersonData base class
{
private:
    int customerNumber;
    bool mailingList;

public:
    CustomerData() // Default constructor
    {
        customerNumber = 0;
        mailingList = 0;
    }

    CustomerData(int cNum, bool mailL) // Constructor 1
    {
        setCustomerNumber(cNum);
        setMailingList(mailL);
    }

    // Accessor Functions for child class
    int getCustomerNumber() const
    {
        return customerNumber;
    }

    bool getMailingList() const
    {
        if (mailingList != 0)
        {

            cout << "On Mailing List!: ";
            return mailingList;
        }

        else (mailingList == 0);
        {
            cout << "Not on mailing list!: ";
            return mailingList;
        }
    }

    // Mutator Functions for child class
    void setCustomerNumber(int cNum)
    {
        customerNumber = cNum;
    }

    void setMailingList(bool mailL)
    {
        mailingList = mailL;
    }
};

class PreferredCustomer :public CustomerData // child class of CustomerData child class
{
private:
    double purchasesAmount;
    double discountLevel;
public:

    PreferredCustomer() // default constructor
    {
            purchasesAmount = 0;
            discountLevel = 0;
    }

    PreferredCustomer(string aLname, string aFname, string aAddress, 
        string aCity, string aState, int aZip, string aPhone, int cn, 
        bool ml, double Pa, double dl)   // constructor 1
    {
        double Pa;
        double dl;
    }

    // Mutator Functions
    void setPurchasesAmount(double Pa)
    {
        purchasesAmount = Pa;
    }

    // Accessor Functions
    double getPurchasesAmount() const
    {
        return purchasesAmount;
    }

    double getDiscountLevel() const
    {
        return discountLevel;
    }

    void addPurchase(double P) const
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    CustomerData Cdata;       // for access of child class functions
    PersonData Pdata;         // for access of parent class functions
    PreferredCustomer PCdata; // for access of preferred customer class functions
    string     temp1;         // Temporary variable for string values
    int        temp2,         // Temporary variable for integer values
        max = 100,            // For-loop maximum loop value
        i;                    // i variable
    bool       temp3;         // Temporary variable for bool values

    for (i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
        // Input Data
        cout << "Please input first Name: ";
        getline(cin, temp1);
        Pdata.setFirstName(temp1);

        cout << "Please input last Name: ";
        getline(cin, temp1);
        Pdata.setLastName(temp1);

        cout << "Please input address: ";
        getline(cin, temp1);
        Pdata.setAddress(temp1);

        cout << "Please input city: ";
        getline(cin, temp1);
        Pdata.setCity(temp1);

        cout << "Please input state: ";
        getline(cin, temp1);
        Pdata.setState(temp1);

        cout << "Please input Zip code: ";
        cin >> temp2;
        Pdata.setZip(temp2);

        cin.ignore(); // discards unread char from cin

        cout << "Please input Phone Number: ";
        getline(cin, temp1);
        Pdata.setPhone(temp1);

        cout << "Enter 1 to be included in mail list," << endl;
        cout << "Enter 0 to not be included in mail list: ";
        cin >> temp3;
        Cdata.setMailingList(temp3);

        Cdata.setCustomerNumber(i); // set customer number

        cout << endl << endl;

        cout << "Name: " << Pdata.getFirstName() << ", " << Pdata.getLastName() << " \n";
        cout << "Customer Number: " << Cdata.getCustomerNumber() << "\n";
        cout << "Address: " << Pdata.getAddress() << "\n";
        cout << "City: " << Pdata.getCity() << "\n";
        cout << "State: " << Pdata.getState() << "\n";
        cout << "Phone: " << Pdata.getPhone() << "\n";
        cout << "Zip: " << Pdata.getZip() << "\n";
        cout << Cdata.getMailingList() << "\n";

        cout << endl << endl;
        cin.ignore(); // discards unread char from cin
    }

    char c;
    cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you define two unused local variables inside the constructor?  That's the problem.  There's a name conflict between the parameter list and the local variables.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor's purpose is to take the parameters the are passed in and construct the object from the class declaration and initialize members as appropriate.  It not only has to initialize the class but also all the base classes as well, this can be done by passing parameters to the base constructor(s).

In

```
PreferredCustomer(string aLname, string aFname, string aAddress, 
            string aCity, string aState, int aZip, string aPhone, int cn, 
            bool ml, double Pa, double dl)   // constructor 1
{
    double Pa;
    double dl;
}
```

1. You aren't initializing anything
2. You are declaring two local parameters that match (and conflict with) the parameters passed in
3. You don't call the base's constructors (how most of the work is done)

   `PreferredCustomer(...) :CustomerData(...)`

   `CustomerData(...) :PersonData(...)`
4. You don't initialize this class's members

   ```
   purchasesAmount = pa;
   discountLevel = dl;
   ```

Comment: Can anyone help with how to embed the source lines in the list.  It looks really ugly and I can't figure out how to make it work.  I would have done better with the example if not the struggle with the formatting.